# GlazedLists AutoCompleteSupport and searching custom objects

Tags: java, autocomplete, jcombobox, glazedlists

I am trying to get AutoCompleteSupport to search for a specific string in an object, but when I assign the EventList to the JComboBox, I don't understand how to instruct the installer to query only the Station object's "title" property only. Instead the AutoCompleteSupport searches the entire object name string. Is there another thing that I need to implement, to tell the AutoCompleteSupport to search only across this one set of properties in a particular object?

Code thus far:

```
public class StationFinder extends JComboBox {
    private EventList<Station> stations = new BasicEventList<Station>();

    public StationFinder() {
        setStations(); // this sets up the 'stations' property

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                 AutoCompleteSupport.install(StationFinder.this, getStations());
            }

        });
    }
}
```

This is the Station object:

```
public class Station {
private int id;
private String metaName;
private String title;

...

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMetaName() {
    return metaName;
}

public void setMetaName(String metaName) {
    this.metaName = metaName;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

}

I've tried implementing FilterableText within the Station object, but that didn't work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you're trying to extend the combobox in order to install the auto-complete support.

Here's a small, yet complete sample program. I didn't know what type of station you were referring to so in my example I'm thinking about radio stations in the UK. I'm listing their name and their location.

The key aspect is the TextFilterator. If you tried installing without the filterator then you'd find that the auto-complete would also match the location too (because that's output in the toString() and by default that's where the filtering is taking place). However, once it is included I can specify precisely the fields of interest - ie title - and only the station title is matched in the filtering.

```
import ca.odell.glazedlists.BasicEventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.EventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.TextFilterator;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.matchers.TextMatcherEditor;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.AutoCompleteSupport;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.EventComboBoxModel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class StationFinderAutoComplete {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JComboBox stationsComboBox;
    private EventList<Station> stations = new BasicEventList<Station>();

    public StationFinderAutoComplete() {
        populateStations();
        createGui();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void populateStations() {
        stations.add(new Station("Key 103", "Manchester"));
        stations.add(new Station("Capital FM", "London"));
        stations.add(new Station("BBC Radio Leeds", "Leeds"));
        stations.add(new Station("BBC Radio 4", "London"));
    }

    private void createGui() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("GlazedLists Autocomplete Example");
        mainFrame.setSize(600, 400);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Use a GlazedLists EventComboBoxModel to connect the JComboBox with an EventList.
        EventComboBoxModel<Station> model = new EventComboBoxModel<Station>(stations);
        stationsComboBox = new JComboBox(model);

        AutoCompleteSupport autocomplete = AutoCompleteSupport.install(stationsComboBox, stations, new StationTextFilterator());
        // Try without the filterator to see the difference.
        //AutoCompleteSupport autocomplete = AutoCompleteSupport.install(stationsComboBox, stations);
        autocomplete.setFilterMode(TextMatcherEditor.CONTAINS);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(stationsComboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new StationFinderAutoComplete();
            }
        });
    }

    class Station {

        private String title;
        private String location;

        public Station(String title, String location) {
            this.title = title;
            this.location = location;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return title + " (" + location + ")";
        }
    }

    class StationTextFilterator implements TextFilterator<Station> {
        @Override
        public void getFilterStrings(List<String> baseList, Station station) {
            baseList.add(station.getTitle());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean the line of code with `AutoCompleteSupport.install`. Yes, all these packages are available with the standard GlazedLists package. My point is whether you pass the TextFilterator to the `AutoCompleteSupport.install()` method, and nothing to do with you installing the package on your system.

Comment: Sorry found it. Was looking for an extension, instead of an implementation. =)

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Is something missing from my sample or explanation which preventing you from tagging as answered? I'd happily expand my answer if necessary.

Comment: Okay I think your code worked. =) I removed the TextFilterator as you noted, and there was no effective difference. I don't quite understand that part, but it works the same with or without. Thank you! Now onto listening for a selection event =D

Comment: That shouldn't happen. In my example code, if you use the use the commented out `AutoCompleteSupport.install()` method (no filterator) and you try typing "London" you'll get match the two stations with London as their location. If you revert to using the original install method with the filterator and try again with "London" you'll get no matches. That's the difference - do you see that when you run yourself?

Comment: I think I see why. Yes, your Station definition is different from mine (no, this does not involve broadcast radio stations btw). I am only querying the "title", and your code queries both "title" and "location". That's why you see different results than I do. Thank you, for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56789/discussion-between-arooaroo-and-chris-walsh).

Comment: Whilst searching the net for GlazedLists Autocomplete Support on object I stumbled on this very useful thread.Having tested the answer provided by @arooaroo all works fine in terms of what I am looking for. The question I have is that how can I then add support such that I can populate other fields upon item selection on my Autocomplete featured form control? Or should I rather ask a separate question that extends this one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LuyandaSiko I regret that I'm finding your question ambiguous so I'm not entirely sure of the problem you're trying to solve. Regardless, my sense is that it's sufficiently distinct that it ought to be a separate question rather than a follow up.